# openvpn - prevent clients to access openvpn servers local network

Tags: linux, openvpn

I have openvpn setup on my server

My hosting provider doesn't like network scans from their server and so i want to disable client devices connected to my openvpn to do a nmap scan for example

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: AFAIK the only way to prevent scans would be rules that block everything except what you specifically need to permit.  Without knowing what the goal is for this specific VPN is, it is hard to make any specific suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you can completely stop them from doing scans. But you could assign them addresses in a VPN only IP address range and have restrictive firewall (iptables) rules which only allow traffic to the services you want to expose to your VPN clients.

Hope this helps.